# What is the difference between sendWithCompletionHandler and invokeProcedure of Mobilefirst Platform?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Form the "Objective-C client-side API for iOS apps Reference", I found invoking adapter from iOS application use sendWithCompletionHandler and invokeProcedure. But what is the difference of these two methods in swift?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I do not understand the question. Can you please rephrase?

Comment: check this link https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/invoking-adapter-procedures-native-ios-swift-applications/

Answer (score 0):

Repasting a deleted answer:

### sendWithCompletionHandler:

it is objective c or swift api for  client side invoke adapter resource from native application(iOS)

Sends request to resource. The request must have been initialized with a valid path.

```
- (void)sendWithCompletionHandler:(void ( ^ ) ( IMFResponse *response , NSError *error ))completionHandler
```

**Parameters**
completionHandler

- Block to be called when the request is completed

**Discussion**

If the request is completed successfully, the error parameter of the completion block is nil and the response parameter contains the server response. If the request fails, the error parameter is not nil and contains an error description. The response parameter may contain a response from the server, or may be nil.

Declared In

```
IMFResourceRequest.h
```

more check this link https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/invoking-adapter-procedures-native-ios-swift-applications/

### invokeProcedure:

```
WL.Client.invokeProcedure
```

This method invokes a procedure that is exposed by an IBM® Worklight® adapter
and it is  javascript api for  client side invoke adapter resource from hybrid application( i.e iOS , android and  windows 8)

Syntax

```
WL.Client invokeProcedure (invocationData, options)
```

more check this link https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_client_invokeprocedure.html